# how to number <images> tags with XSLT

Tags: xslt

output:

```
<imgs>
<image>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-6287sku-6287.jpg</image>
<image>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-6287sku-6287,1.jpg</image>
<image>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-6287sku-6287,2.jpg</image>
<image>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-6287sku-6287,3.jpg</image>
<image>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-6287sku-6287,4.jpg</image>
</imgs>
```

Version:

```
XSLT 1.0
```

Can anyone help us, can we use xslt to convert to number the tags?

Except result:

```
<imgs>
<image1>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-6287sku-6287.jpg</image1>
<image2>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-6287sku-6287,1.jpg</image2>
<image3>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-6287sku-6287,2.jpg</image3>
<image4>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-6287sku-6287,3.jpg</image4>
<image5>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-6287sku-6287,4.jpg</image5>
</imgs>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried IN your question and your challenges with that so that we may assist you in fixing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this template:

```
  <xsl:template match="imgs">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="image">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}{position()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Or as @michael.hor257k in comment suggest, even simpeler:

```
  <xsl:template match="imgs">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="image">
        <xsl:element name="image{position()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: When will `name()` NOT return `"image"`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Correct, and the position() the numbering.

Comment: I meant: why are you using `<xsl:element name="{name()}{position()}">` instead of simply `<xsl:element name="image{position()}">`?

Comment: You are right again...I will change that.

Comment: @Siebie Jongebloed  here is our full code. https://ibb.co/gtjX9FF But after paste your code we get:  Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /home/fs/domains/public_html/pub/ line 18 element template in /home/fs/domains/public_html/vendor/firebear/importexport/Model/Output/Xslt.php on line 107

Comment: You can not use a xsl:template inside a xsl:template as the picture shows. It is hard to understand what you are trying to do with xslt in a picture that is not formatted. Please just ask a new question on stackoverflow with your current xsl and with a small but good example of your source-xml and what you would like as result

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I describe everything here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689993/issue-with-number-tags-via-xslt with full code