# Issue with number tags via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Output date:

```
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1">
<product>
<sku>SKU 11077</sku>
<imgs>
<image>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077.jpg</image>
<image>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,1.jpg</image>
<image>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,2.jpg</image>
<image>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,3.jpg</image>
<image>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,4.jpg</image>
</imgs>
</product>
</products>
```

I try convert using `XSLT 1.0` to get result number tags `<image1>`:

```
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1">
<product>
<sku>SKU 11077</sku>
<image1>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077.jpg</image1>
<image2>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,1.jpg</image2>
<image3>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,2.jpg</image3>
<image4>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,3.jpg</image4>
<image5>https://testtest.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,4.jpg</image5>
</product>
</products>
```

I try to do via code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="products">
<xsl:element name="products">
  <xsl:for-each select="product">
    <xsl:element name="product">
         <xsl:element name="sku">
             <xsl:value-of select="sku"/>
         </xsl:element>
     <xsl:template match="imgs">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="image">
        <xsl:element name="image{position()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
                    
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I get issue:**

But after paste your code we get: Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /home/fs/domains/public_html/pub/ line 18 element template in /home/fs/domains/public_html/vendor/firebear/importexport/Model/Output/Xslt.php on line 107

Can someone help me format this?

Comment: is number tags <image1> <image2> <image3>

Comment: Hm, it's been a while but I am not sure if you can have a template _in_ a template...

Comment: yes this is the bug and we are trying to solve it. Because the content is behind <products> and the following photos are behind <imgs>in tag <image>

Comment: Yes, I am pretty confident you need to use `<apply-templates />`

Comment: Could you please try help us in answer and add this code in our code? Then we try in our website.

Comment: Uh, my XSL is really rusty and I cannot test right now. I know it's w3schools, but have a look into this: https://www.w3schools.com/XML/ref_xsl_el_template.asp. Should give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates cannot be nested.

***--- edited in response to your changing the expected result ---***

AFAICT, the result you want can be produced quite simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@version"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="sku"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="imgs/image">
                    <xsl:element name="image{position()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="imgs">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
    <xsl:element name="image{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. Do not use `xsl:element` where a [literal result element](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#literal-result-element) will suffice.

Comment: michael.hor257k, I appreciate your efforts. I have tried all methods. But I still can't get photos <image1> <image2> As to download these photos I need to generate the photos before <imgs> https://ibb.co/cTds0gx

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me at this point. You can see that the code above produces the exact result specified in your question (before you changed it while I was writing this comment): http://xsltransform.net/6qM2JJd I don't know what you mean by "download these photos".

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT (imgs-element not needed)**

Wel just use `xsl:apply-templates` with a `select="imgs"` so a next template match will catch your imgs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:element name="products">
      <xsl:for-each select="product">
        <xsl:element name="product">
          <xsl:element name="sku">
            <xsl:value-of select="sku"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="imgs"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="imgs">
    <xsl:for-each select="image">
      <xsl:element name="image{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But while you are only changing those image-elements you could make it simpeler using a generic copy-template like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity template : copy all nodes and attributes -->   
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="imgs">
    <xsl:for-each select="image">
      <xsl:element name="image{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Siebie Jongebloed  I appreciate your efforts. I have tried all methods. But I still can't get photos <image1> <image2> As to download these photos I need to generate the photos before <imgs> https://ibb.co/cTds0gx

Comment: I have no clue on how your html is generated. New question again...